# propagating error upwards in java

Tags: java

I have a main class where I have something like

```
void FooBar(String s){

  try {
    parseString(s);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    context.getCounter(Counters.ERROR).increment(1); // this increment doesnt increases
  }
}
```

parseString is

```
void ParseString(String s){
  if (matcher.matches()) {

  } else {
    //throw exception
    try {
      throw new Exception("bad formatted N-triples");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But for some reason, the error is not propagated upwards. In my FooBar method the error counters are not incremented even if the function gets bad formatted data.

How do I propagate this exception upwards?

Comment: Why are you throwing an exception if you just catch it in the catch block?

Comment: rethrow it, or don't catch it

Comment: You should never throw `Exception`.  Always choose a more appropriate exception provided by the JVM, or throw your own custom exception.  This allows other parts of your program to handle your specific exception without catching exceptions that might occur in your progrsm that you do not know how to handle.

Comment: I know this is "example" code, but you should NEVER start a Java method name with an uppercase letter!

Answer (score 9):

> But for some reason, the error is not propagated upwards...

The reason it is not propagated upwards is that you caught it.  Exceptions stop propagating when they are caught.

Either don't catch it in `parseString`, or rethrow it in the handler; e.g. `e.printStackTrace(); throw e;`

---

However, this is likely to get you into more problems, specifically because of the exception you are catching / throwing here.  The problem is that `Exception` is the root of all checked exceptions:

- Since it is a checked exception, the method `parseString` must declare that it `throws` the `Exception` if you want to the exception to propagate.
- But `throws Exception` is saying that this method could throw any possible checked exception ... which makes life difficult for the caller.  (Not in this example ... but in general.)

My advice is as follows:

- Avoid creating / throwing `Exception`.  Pick a more specific (checked or unchecked) exception that reflects the meaning of the "exceptional event" you are trying to report ... or implement your own exception class.  In this case throwing `IllegalArgumentException` would probably be better, though that is an unchecked exception.
- Avoid situations where you need to propagate `Exception`.
- Be careful when you catch `Exception`.  It catches every (non-`Error`) exception, including all of the unchecked ones; i.e. `RuntimeExecption` and its subclasses.

Comment: `catch (Exception up) { throw up; }`

Answer (score 3):

You either don't catch it in `ParseString`, or you rethrow it with `throw e;`

Once an exception is caught, it doesn't get propagated unless you `throw` it again.

Answer (score 3):

Examine what you're doing here:

```
try {
  throw new Exception("bad formatted N-triples");//You throw an exception!
} catch (Exception e) {//And immediately catch it!
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Because the exception is caught, it will not propagate. Instead, remove the try/catch block and simply throw the exception:

```
void ParseString(String s){
  if (matcher.matches()) {
    //code for reasons
  } else {
    //throw exception
    throw new Exception("bad formatted N-triples");
  }
}
```

Note that this is actually bad practice. You want to say something about your exception, and declare it:

```
void ParseString(String s) throws IllegalArgumentException {
  if (matcher.matches()) {
    //code for reasons
  } else {
    //throw exception
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad formatted N-triples");
  }
}
```

The surrounding function should know how to cope with that exception explicitly, rather than just throwing it's hands up because it's a general exception.

Comment: Don't forget to add `throws Exception` to the method declaration.

Comment: Just a side note: [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) is an unchecked exception, so you don't actually need to declare it.

Comment: Sure... but it doesn't hurt. Also, in truly clean code he'd use a more specific exception that he probably created.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't surround your error with try/catch:

```
void ParseString(String s){
  if (matcher.matches()) {

        }
        else{
            //throw exception
            throw new Exception("bad formatted N-triples");}
        }
}
```

When you throw the error, it's caught in the catch statement within `parseString` method, which is why isn't isn't propagated to the top.

Ideally, you'd do:

```
void ParseString(String s) throws Exception  {
  if (matcher.matches()) {

        }
        else{
            //throw exception
            throw new Exception("bad formatted N-triples");}
        }
}
```

Comment: I originally had this.. but eclipse suggested Unhandled exception type Exception and then i had a try catch block..

Comment: @Fraz Read the error. You need `void ParseString(String s) throws Exception {`

Comment: You've specified `throws IllegalArgumentException` and yet you throw a regular `Exception`. Typo was here? :)

Comment: Yes, sorry... Thank you. Fixed.